# Instead of script src address attribute put source directly

Tags: javascript, shopify

I have a code that's working:

```
if (typeof Checkout === 'object') {
if (typeof Checkout.$ === 'function') {
    (function(src) {
        var tagName = 'script',
            script = document.createElement(tagName);
        script.src = src;
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        head.insertBefore(script, head.childNodes[0]);
    })('https://www.conversionpirate.com/pirate-countdown.js');
}
```

}

But I don't want to have reference to conversionpirate site since it's plain js that I can directly paste there. The problem is I don't know how to do it - I tried to put `pirate-countdown.js` code inside that method but failed. I'm sure it's quite easy, but required knowledge about it. Could someone help me with this one?

Comment: Are you asking us to help you pirate someone else's code?

Comment: Why pirate? I can write myself similar code, but it's ready there. I just don't want to be dependent on other site's will.

Comment: Can't you just download the `pirate-countdown.js` file to your site's root then just reference it from there? i.e., instead of `https://www.conversionpirate.com/pirate-countdown.js`, you have `/pirate-countdown.js`.

Comment: @Nelson Yeung I tried that, but I use Shopify and `.liquid` reference doesn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Work normally just by adding html element with `main__header class` and `time id` as beleow :

```html
<script src="https://www.conversionpirate.com/pirate-countdown.js"></script>

<div class="main__header">
</div>
<div id="time">

</div>
```

Also if your still facing probleme make directly their code into your js file or just create new js file and refernce it loccally :

see below snipet :

```js
function create(htmlStr) {
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = htmlStr;
    while (temp.firstChild) {
        frag.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
    }
    return frag;
}

function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var start = Date.now(),
        diff,
        minutes,
        seconds;
    function timer() {
        diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

        minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
        seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds; 

        if (diff <= 0) {
            start = Date.now() + 1000;
        }
    };
    timer();
    setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
 
 var fragment3 = create('<div style="background:#fff5d2;padding:10px 20px;border:1px solid #e3df74; font-size:14px; color:#2c2c2c; font-weight:bold;-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; margin:10px 0px 20px 0px">Your order is reserved for <span id="time"></span> minutes!</div>');
 document.getElementsByClassName('main__header')[0].appendChild(fragment3);


 var ten = 60 * 10,
 display = document.querySelector('#time');
  
 startTimer(ten, display);
};
```

```html
<div class="main__header">
</div>
<div id="time">

</div>
```

Comment: The problem with Shopify is that I can't reference assets just like that - I would normally do that since I know JS basics, but in this case I can't do that :/

Comment: Have you tried to create js localy then create lequid file  ?

Comment: Yes, I put `countdown-pirate.js` in /assets and tried to use `script.src= "{{ 'countdown-pirate.js' | asset_url }}"` but it doesn't fetch static adress.

Comment: That's why I wanted to have all the code in one piece so I could paste it in JS snippet section in Online Store -> Preferences